# Post Installation Error: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: octave

I downloaded Octave from the [official website](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/download.html). I have Windows 10 OS with sufficient space in my system. But after installation, when I try to open Octave GUI, I get this error:

[image: error]

How to fix this?

Comment: Did you try running octave.vbs 8nstead, does it give the same response? Did you try a reboot?

Comment: @NickJ, thanks for your response! 
I tried the octave.vbs after a reboot of my system. Unfortunately the same error message popped up.

Comment: ok. line 63 of that script is trying to execute `\bin\octave-gui.exe` under the mingw64 folder (if i read it right, it will run the mingw64 version if it sees a `\bin\octave-cli.exe` under that folder, otherwise it'll run the files under mingw32.)  can you see and manually run any of those files?